# Занести данные в массив

Tags: массивы, c++

Привет. Данные вводятся вот так:

```
1 2
3 4
```

где 1 строка - ее нужно занести как 1 строку 2-мерного массива и 2 строку как 2 строку двумерного массива.

Не подскажите как можно сделать, срочно нужно

Comment: Вам срочно нужно почитать книжку по C++. Любую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int a[2][2];
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i ++)
    cin >> a[i / 2][i % 2];
  return 0;
}
```

Вот так должно работать

Comment: Зачем так сложно? А два вложенных цикла уже не модно?